# Добавление отчёта FastReport.Net на форму

Tags: fastreport

Работаю с FastReport.Net. Элемент Report не добавляется на форму. Dll при добавлении на панель элементов брал из GAS. На сайте FastReport сказано, что в данному случае надо зарегистрировать dll в GAS(https://www.fastreport.ru/ru/faq/18/243/), но они уже зарегистрированы. Не очень понимаю, в чём может быть еще пролема

Answer (score 0):

Было достаточно добавить FastReport.dll в ссылки проекта. В мануале для разработчиков об это ни слова.